# Is it possible in iOS 8 to use swipe to go back on TableviewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6

So i'm using navigation controller to segue from a View controller A(VCA) to multiple other controllers: View controller B(VCB), TableView Controller A(TCA) , and TableView Controller B(TCB). When i segue from VCA to VCB , I can swipe left to right and I return to VCA . But the problem I run into is that this same feature does/t work when I go from VCA to TCA or VCA to TCB. I can however just click on the back button and it takes be back to VCA, but I wanted that extra gesture feature. IS it possible to achieve what I want, or Is the only option Is to create 2 View controllers and insert Tableview in each?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the steps you just described. Perhaps you added some gesture recognizer that's interfering with the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: I had added a bar button item and labeled it back as a exit segue. removed it and it works